# (complex variables) Express $\cos3\phi$, $\cos4\phi$, and $\cos5\phi$ in terms of $\cos\phi$ and $\sin\phi$.

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I'm not sure what the intuition is supposed to be behind this question. This is my attempt at $\cos3\phi$. Does this look agreeable?

We can use the identity $e^{iz}=\cos z + i \sin z$. Let $z = 3 \phi$. 
\begin{align*}
\cos3\phi &= Re\left( e^{i3\phi} \right) \\
&= Re\left( \left( e^{i\phi} \right)^3 \right) \\
&= Re \left( \cos^3\phi + 2i\cos^2\phi\sin\phi - \cos\phi\sin^2\phi + i \cos^2\phi \sin \phi - 2 \cos\phi\sin^2\phi -i\sin^3\phi \right) \\
&= \cos^3\phi - 3\cos\phi\sin^2\phi
\end{align*}

And I suppose a similar argument would follow for $\cos4\phi$ and $\cos5\phi$. But is there an easier way than manually factoring $(\cos3\phi + i\sin3\phi)^4$ and $(\cos3\phi + i\sin3\phi)^5$?

Comment: It looks like it's the right thing to do.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula#Formulas_for_cosine_and_sine_individually

Comment: I made an edit to my post. I suppose my question is: is there a better way to do it than manually factoring out the expression?

Comment: You can use the binomial theorem to write the expansion compactly, but the essence is still just multiplying out the factors.

Comment: But once you expanded $\cos(2\phi)$ getting $\cos(3\phi)$ becomes simple and then from $\cos(3\phi)$ to $\cos(4\phi)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

we can define reduction formulae of $\cos(mx)$ as follows:

$$\cos(2n+1)x+\cos x=2\cos(n+1)x\cos nx$$

$$\cos(2n)x+\cos2x=2\cos(n+1)x\cos(n-1)x$$

and for $\sin(mx),$

$$\sin(2n+1)x-\sin x=2\sin nx\cos(n+1)x$$

$$\sin(2n)x-\sin2x=2\sin(n-1)x\cos(n+1)x\text{ or }=2\sin(nx)\cos(nx)$$

Answer (score 0):

using the addition formulas we obtain
$\cos(3\phi)=4\, \left( \cos \left( \phi \right)  \right) ^{3}-3\,\cos \left( \phi
 \right)         
$
$\cos(4\phi)=8\, \left( \cos \left( \phi \right)  \right) ^{4}-8\, \left( \cos \left( 
\phi \right)  \right) ^{2}+1$
$\cos(5\phi)=16\, \left( \cos \left( \phi \right)  \right) ^{5}-20\, \left( \cos
 \left( \phi \right)  \right) ^{3}+5\,\cos \left( \phi \right) 
$
Sonnhard.

Comment: What are the "addition formulas"?

Comment: @flapjackery $\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos\alpha \cos\beta -\sin\alpha \sin\beta$ and $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin\alpha \cos\beta +\cos\alpha \sin\beta$